# How can an existing 2D AxesSubplot object be converted/upgraded to an Axes3DSubplot object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Assume I have some matplotlib code that looks like the following:

```
### import statements, etc. ###

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)

### plot some 2D data to ax1 ###

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')

### plot some 3D data to ax2 ###
```

The effect of the `ax2 = ...` line is to remove whatever was plotted to `ax1`, and to create a new Axes3DSubplot object.

My question is:  how can I get an `ax2` object (having the same subplot position as `ax1` had) which has a 3D projection and which "imports" all of the 2D data that was previously plotted to `ax1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the data from the `2D-Axes` in the corresponding `3D-Axes`. Example:

get from this:

[image]

plot here:

[image]

This is the code used for the above example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
plt.ion()
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax1.plot([1,2,3,4])
ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax2.plot([4,3,2,1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
ax3.plot([4,3,2,1])
ax4 = plt.subplot(224)
ax4.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.show()

plt.figure()
ax1_3d = plt.subplot(221, projection='3d')
ax2_3d = plt.subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax3_3d = plt.subplot(223, projection='3d')
ax4_3d = plt.subplot(224, projection='3d')
[ax1_3d.plot(*ax1.lines[i].get_data()) for i,v in enumerate(ax1.lines)]
[ax2_3d.plot(*ax2.lines[i].get_data()) for i,v in enumerate(ax2.lines)]
[ax3_3d.plot(*ax3.lines[i].get_data()) for i,v in enumerate(ax3.lines)]
[ax4_3d.plot(*ax4.lines[i].get_data()) for i,v in enumerate(ax4.lines)]
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a nice example, and it almost answers my question -- I want to avoid the plt.figure() call in your code, and simply replace an existing subplot of the first figure.  If you can modify your answer (or add to it) so there's an example with the data temporarily stored (or something more space efficient?), and rewritten to the same subplot location, I'd be happy to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a resurrection, but I came across this same issue today and found a solution, based mostly off of @Saullo Castro's answer. This example uses one subplot, but the idea is the same no matter how many you have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Initial 2d axes
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.plot([1,2,3,4])

# Create Axes3D and plot the 2d data on it
ax1_3d = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')
[ax1_3d.plot(*ax1.lines[i].get_data()) for i,v in enumerate(ax1.lines)]

# Important step: turn off the old 2d axes!
ax1.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

Comment: why is turning off the 2d axes necessary?  I don't see a difference with or without that line of code.

Comment: It may not be necessary in all cases, but turning it off prevents anything from the 2d axes from getting rendered. I suppose it's a "better safe than sorry" measure.